# php preg_replace each occurence with different string

Tags: php, regex, html, preg-replace

Suppose there is a string    `$comment = "I am tagging @abc and @def here"`.
Now I want to replace every word starting with   `@`, with a link whose href attribute and link text is what follows    `@` in the word. Please see the example below for more clarification.
Like    `@abc` should be replaced with    `abc` and    `@def` should be replaced with    `def` in the href attribute and the link text too.
The result should be something like :    `$comment = "I am tagging <a href='abc'>abc</a> and <a href='def'>def</a> here"`.
I have tried it but I am totally blank about this. Please comment if you have any problems in understanding the question.
Thanks In Advance! :)

Comment: Whosoever downvoted it, atleast please specify a reason for that.

Comment: *I have tried it* - what?

Comment: @splash58 Obviously what I have desired for in the question. It's just I don't know how to replace every occurence differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a regular expression to find all text ending with a word boundary (`\b`) that begin with `@`. For each of those, you extract the text after the `@` and build the anchor tag with that:

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/@.+?\b/', function($m) {
    $str = substr($m[0], 1);
    return sprintf("<a href='%s'>%s</a>", $str, $str);
}, $comment);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works at the moment. I will make some checks and then accept the answer.

Comment: I added some explanation to the answer, maybe it helps

Comment: Do you have any idea how to put the all the returned strings from     `return sprintf()` above into a different array as separate elements?

Comment: `$array = array(); preg_replace_callback(...., function($m) use($array) { ... $array[] = $m[0]; ...}, ...);`    I guess the `use($array)` is probably what you are looking for to be able to use a variable declared outside the callback function

Comment: This does not seem to work.    `$array` does not contain anything after this.

Comment: Yes it should be `use(&$array)` instead of `use($array)`. So now with slight adaptation also to the regex, it will be `$array = array(); preg_replace_callback('/@(.+?)\b/', function($m) use(&$array) { $array[]= $m[1]; }, $comment);`

Answer (score 2):

You can do the replacement using a single search and replace:

```
<?php

$string="I am tagging @abc and @def here";

$search='/\@(\w+)/';
$r='<a href="\1">\1</a>';

$s=preg_replace($search, $r, $string);

echo $s.PHP_EOL;
```

When run, it gives:

```
$ php -f t.php 
I am tagging <a href="abc">abc</a> and <a href="def">def</a> here
```

Comment: An answer mentioned    `/@.+?\b/` as the regex. What is the difference between that regex and the regex you used? And could all the strings replaced be placed in a separate array?

Comment: `\w` matches only word characters, while the other solution matches any character up to a word boundary. In practice not much difference.

Answer (score -1):

I would use a callback variation of preg_replace.  The callback is called once for each match.  Putting what you actually want to use as your associative array index as a grouped match puts it as the second item in the $matches array.

Eg:

```
$res = preg_replace_callback( 
    "/@([a-z]+)/",
    function ( $matches ){
        $links = array( 'abc' => 'http://....abc', 'def' => 'http://....def' );
        return $links[ $matches[ 1 ] ];
    },
    "I am tagging @abc and @def here"
);

echo $res;
```

Comment: I cannot specify    `$links` array since I the number of    `@` in the array can be variable.

Comment: I misunderstood your requirements.